# Get the complete structure of a program?

Tags: python, coding-style

I would have a quite simple question, but can't find any suitable automated solution for now.

I have developed an algorithm that performs a lot of stuff (image processing in fact) in Python.

What I want to do now is to optimize it. And for that, I would love to create a graph of my algorithm.

Kind of an UML chart or sequencial chart in fact, in which functions would be displayed with inputs and ouptuts.

My algorithm does not imply complex stuff, and is mainly based on a = f(b) operations (no databases, hardware stuff, server, . . . )

Would you have any hint?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML generation is provided by pyreverse - it's part of pylint package

It generates UML in dot format - or png, etc.

It creates UML diagram, so you can easily see **basic** structure of your code

I'm not sure if it satisfy all your needs, but it might be helpful

Comment: Thanks men, both your answers are quite good ! I used pycallgraph to easily get a graph of the functions of my software, and was already capable of removing orphans.

Comment: Would there be a more "data centric" solution? In which one could know which variables of your code are created and calculated but finally not used?

Comment: pylint (variable not used and a lot of more, 'must have' tool for python), pychecker (but it executes the code, not just analyze it), pep8 (for conventions)

Comment: I'll definitely look at that and come back with answers. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2007/11/14/generating-call-graphs-for-understanding-and-refactoring-python-code/